# Facebook SDK 4.0 AppInviteDialog with callback

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

In the new Fb SDK 4.0 for Android you can register a callback for the LoginButton according to the docs. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3

The question is is this possible for the AppInviteDialog as well? Or is there any other way to identify if the App-Invite was successful or not?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

```
public static void openDialogInvite(final Activity activity)
{
    String appLinkUrl, previewImageUrl;

    appLinkUrl = "your app link url";
    previewImageUrl = "https://www.example.com/my_invite_image.jpg";

    if (AppInviteDialog.canShow())
    {
        AppInviteContent content = new AppInviteContent.Builder()
                .setApplinkUrl(appLinkUrl)
                .setPreviewImageUrl(previewImageUrl)
                .build();

        AppInviteDialog appInviteDialog = new AppInviteDialog(activity);
        CallbackManager sCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        appInviteDialog.registerCallback(sCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<AppInviteDialog.Result>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(AppInviteDialog.Result result)
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel()
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e)
            {
            }
        });

        appInviteDialog.show(content);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to get the selected friends? As far as I know, this version doesn't pass their id in the AppInviteDialog.Result.

Comment: @Proverbio You are correct. Afaik, FB will no longer give us the selected friends because they don't want developers to incentivize inviting friends.

Comment: Thank you that worked like a charm, I also forgot to add onActivityResult() with the callback in it so that should be considered as well if somebody has the same issue.

Comment: Does anyone else get fail after you press invite? The applink is correct, it just doesn't send the invite.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue as DDsix.  Everything in the client indicates that the invite was a success, including the Callback, however the user never receives the invite on Facebook.

Comment: Also need to provide  onActivityResult implementation to get callback.     
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

Comment: As @shaby mention, this is essential to the answer. here is the snippet http://stackoverflow.com/a/42876956/1284177