# how to set Facebook invite friends callback manager

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I got a peace of code from developer Facebook to invite friends from android app. Its working perfect, but i want to display a message on cancelled or on success. Please see the code below.

```
appLinkUrl = "https://www.myappurl.com";
        previewImageUrl = "http://myimgurl";

        if (AppInviteDialog.canShow()) {
            AppInviteContent content = new AppInviteContent.Builder()
                    .setApplinkUrl(appLinkUrl)
                    .setPreviewImageUrl(previewImageUrl)
                    .build();


            AppInviteDialog.show(this, content);
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook SDK 4.0 AppInviteDialog with callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29515872/facebook-sdk-4-0-appinvitedialog-with-callback)

Comment: i think onResultActivity is missing in that answer?

Comment: yup , so you need to do `callbackManager.onActivityResult( requestCode, resultCode, data );` in `onActivityResult` function

Comment: Thank you i did the same. its working